# Atualizar atributo de um model pelo controller de outro cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2

[RESOLVIDO] Eu tenho uma logica de negocio da seguinte maneira, quando o usuario alterar um atributo para pago (passar de 0 pra 1) preciso que ele atualize o valor do saldo que é de um outro model.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

quando o usuario alterar o status da parcela pra pago que pertence a tabela parcelas quero que seja alterado o valor do saldo que está dentro da tabela contrato

schema: contrato 1 - n parcelas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui com esse codigo:

```
        $this->Iten->Contrato->id=$id;
        $this->Iten->Contrato->saveField("valorTotal",$novoValor);
```